# How to fetch fasta sequences corresponding to header lines in another file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file of lines of headers (`file1`) and another file is sequences in fasta format (`file2`). I want to grep fasta sequences if a header line from `file1` is present in `file2`.

Example:

- `file1`:

  ```
  >sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
  >sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
  ```
- `file2`:

  ```
  >sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
  MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAA
  RGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
  VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFE
  VLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
  ......
  >sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
  MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLL
  GQKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
  VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVE
  LVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI
  ............
  >sp|P0AD68|HUMAN
  MKAAAKTQKPKRQEEHANFISWRFALLCGC
  ILLALAFLLGRVAWLQVISPDMLVKEGDMR
  SLRVQQVSTSRGMITDRSGRPLAVSVPVKA
  IWADPKEVHDAGGISVGDRWKALANALNIP
  .............
  ```
- Desired output

  ```
  >sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
  MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAA
  RGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
  VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFE
  VLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
  ......
  >sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
  MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLL
  GQKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
  VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVE
  LVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI
  ............
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called `fastagrep` which seems to do what you want. Your data are on files data1 and data2:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE1:"
head -20 $FILE1

pl " Input data file $FILE2:"
head -20 $FILE2

pl " Expected output:"
cat $E

pl " Results:"
fastagrep -f $FILE1 $FILE2
```

producing:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
>sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI

-----
 Input data file data2:
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAA
RGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFE
VLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
......
>sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLL
GQKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVE
LVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI
............
>sp|P0AD68|HUMAN
MKAAAKTQKPKRQEEHANFISWRFALLCGC
ILLALAFLLGRVAWLQVISPDMLVKEGDMR
SLRVQQVSTSRGMITDRSGRPLAVSVPVKA
IWADPKEVHDAGGISVGDRWKALANALNIP

-----
 Expected output:
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAA
RGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFE
VLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
......
>sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLL
GQKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVE
LVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI

-----
 Results:
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAA
RGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFE
VLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
......
>sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLL
GQKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVE
LVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI
............
```

This was on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-7-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
perl 5.20.2
```

Details for fastagrep:

```
fastagrep       extract sequences from a multi-FASTA file by regex. (what)
Path    : ~/bin/fastagrep
Version : fastagrep version 0.3
Length  : 392 lines
Type    : Perl script, ASCII text executable
Shebang : #!/usr/bin/env perl
Home    : https://github.com/rec3141/rec-genome-tools (doc)
Modules : (for perl codes)
 strict 1.08
 warnings       1.23
 Getopt::Std    1.10
 IO::File       1.16
 Data::Dumper   2.151_01
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

Given a Fasta file with sequence lines of *equal length*,

```
$ cat file.fa
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAA
RGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFE
VLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
......
>sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLLG
QKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVE
LVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI
............
>sp|P0AD68|HUMAN
MKAAAKTQKPKRQEEHANFISWRFALLCGC
ILLALAFLLGRVAWLQVISPDMLVKEGDMR
SLRVQQVSTSRGMITDRSGRPLAVSVPVKA
IWADPKEVHDAGGISVGDRWKALANALNIP
.............
```

and a query file with the names of the sequences,

```
$ cat query
sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
```

then [`samtools`](http://www.htslib.org/) may be used as

```
$ samtools faidx file.fa -r query
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPPLPSQTDGAARGGTGHLISSTGALGSRSLFSPLRNSMADS
VDSRDIPGLPTNPSRLAAATSETCLLGGFEVLHDKGPLDILNTQIGPSAFRVEVQADGTH
......
>sp|P06616|ERA_ECOLI
MSIDKSYCGFIAIVGRPNVGKSTLLNKLLGQKISITSRKAQTTRHRIVGIHTEGAYQAIY
VDTPGLHMEEKRAINRLMNKAASSSIGDVELVIFVVEGTRWTPDDEMVLNKLREGKAPVI
............
```